# Diseño de base de datos con tablas relacionadas para facturas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

En un diseño de tablas relacionales de base de datos de una factura, he visto que hay que poner una tabla de detalle entre la factura y el producto (relacion muchos a muchos). El la nueva tabla he visto tambien, que se repite el precio, la explicacion es que si se cambia el precio a mitad de temporada, no descuadre el total.
Lo que no entiendo, es si las columnas Precios de las tablas producto y detalle estan relacionadas, o hay que poner el precio por separado en las dos columnas.
Tambien tengo que añadir a la factura, el precio por hora a facturar, que con el tiempo tendera a aumentar. Tengo que hacer lo mismo, hacer una tabla tarifa por ejemplo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: te repito lo mismo que en la otra pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas los dos precios porque expresan cosas distintas. Como dices, uno es el precio del producto y el otro el precio al que se vendió en una determinada factura. Si solo guardas el precio de las líneas, ¿cómo asignas un precio a un producto nuevo? ¿O cómo sabes cuál es el precio actual del producto?

Sobre la tarifa, puede haber varias opciones. Si el detalle guarda el precio final ya calculado, no necesitas guardar la tarifa, a menos que te interese saber ese dato por algún motivo. En cambio, si el precio final lo vas a calcular cada vez que accedas a los datos, necesitarás guardarte tanto la tarifa en ese momento como las horas empleadas. Aunque lo normal diría que es guardar el precio final ya calculado

Comment: gracias por la pronta aclaración, asi que es en la tabla producto, el precio de coste, y en la tabla detalle, el precio en la factura verdad?  Soy bastante nuevo en esto y sobretodo en facturación. voy a ver si te puedo pasar mi base de datos que diseñe, a ver que te parece.